# incorrect syntax near the keyword where c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

when i run the code this erorr apeared 
incorrect syntax near the keyword where c#

```
public SqlDataReader GetDR(CommandType HandelMode, string SQLStat, List<SqlParameter> Parms)
{
    SqlDataReader R = null;
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
    SqlConnection Con = GetConn();
    try
    {
        com.CommandText = SQLStat;
        com.Connection = Con;
        com.CommandType = HandelMode;

        if (Parms != null)
        {
            foreach (SqlParameter P in Parms)
            {
                com.Parameters.Add(P);
            }
        }

        R = com.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        Con.Close();
    }
    return R;
}
```

```
private void pictureBox10_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    List<SqlParameter> ParsList = new List<SqlParameter>();
    string SelectStatement = "Select ID,Aname,Ename,I_D from " + ScreenMasterTableName;
    string Cond = " ID_Co=@ID_Co";
    ParsList.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID_Co", FormInfo.ID_Co));

    if (S_ID.Text != "")
    {
        decimal D = 0;
        decimal.TryParse(S_ID.Text, out D);
        Cond += " and ID=@ID";
        ParsList.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", D));
    }
    if (S_Aname.Text != "")
    {
        if (Cond != "")
            Cond += " and ";
        Cond += " Aname =@Aname";
        ParsList.Add(new SqlParameter("@Aname", S_Aname.Text));
    }

    if (S_Ename.Text != "")
    {
        if (Cond != "")
            Cond += " and ";
        Cond += " Ename =@Ename";
        ParsList.Add(new SqlParameter("@Ename", S_Ename.Text));
    }
    if (Cond != "")
        Cond = " where " + Cond;


    var L = Bus.GetSearchedData(SelectStatement + Cond, ParsList);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = L;
    label9.Text = L.Count.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Show us the final query made by SelectStatement + Cond

Comment: the Second code is final query made by select + cond

Comment: Can you get the query which you debug and show us what exactly the query constructed.

Comment: If you start your debugger and follow your code till the line where the complete sql text is ready for the execution you will find easily the syntax error. In any case if you post that command here we could help you better.

Comment: What's the value of `ScreenMasterTableName`?

Comment: You must show us the contents of `SelectStatement + Cond`.

Comment: your code is confusing. how can `if (Cond == "") ` ever happen ?

Comment: While not the better way to write this, the code above has no apparent _syntax errors_ in the resulting WHERE clause. The only possible points of failure is the name of the table containing spaces or reserved words or something that happens inside the method _GetSearchedData_  (It is not the one showed above)

Comment: By the way, are you sure that you have a column named _I_D_? The where clause uses a column named _ID_CO_

Answer (score -2):

Assuming your s_id is filled in you will have a query like this:

```
where and ID=@ID
```

Comment: `Cond` starts out as `string Cond = " ID_Co=@ID_Co";`

Comment: You're right, makes all the if cond == "" checks superfluous though.